# Error Capture Screen Android by ddms

Tags: android, screen, capture, ddms

Please help me!
I use ddms other to take screenshot on my phone, but It don't work good!

This is screen shot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgMpk.png

I try to capture with emulator or other android phone, it OK. I don't know why!

Thank so much!

Comment: I think it is a driver issue. But I don't know where to start. Maybe telling us what device you use would help.

Comment: Can you compile code on your device? Have you installed OEM drivers for your device? http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the drivers for your device correctly: 
Follow the instructions on here. If you need help I can come to chat to help you out...

http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: thank you, but this isn't my problem. I connected and captured, but i didn't see it clearly. It look at as: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KgMpk.png